# Can a Qt5 program running on X disable minimize and close?

Tags: qt, qt5, x11, metacity

I am writing a C++ Qt5 application that runs on X. The window manager it will run under is [Metacity](https://blogs.gnome.org/metacity/2007/12/23/start-reading-here/). I have a few requirements I'm not sure how to address:

1. Window must not be able to be closed
2. Window must not be able to be minimized
3. Window must always be on top

I have sort of implemented requirement 3 using:

```
setWindowFlags(windowFlags() | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
```

However, right clicking on the window title still shows a popup menu:

[image]

From this menu, the user can turn off the "Always on Top" setting, and the Minimize and Close options are still available. I have tried:

```
setWindowFlags(windowFlags() & ~(Qt::WindowMinMaxButtonsHint | Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint));
```

but, this function doesn't appear to do what I want with this window manager, because no functions get disabled.

One fallback position is:

- Restart the application if it is ever closed (this is already in place for other reasons)
- Restore the window to its normal size if it is ever minimized

Another fallback position is:

- Use `Qt::X11BypassWindowManagerHint` which completely avoids the window manager, and implement window moving and sizing myself somehow.

Ideally, I would like to continue to use the window manager to offer window move and size functionality, yet turn off functions that I don't need.

---

(Please try to avoid comments like "well you shouldn't do that" or "that's a dumb idea" - yes, I know, but this application is not for general use, it's only used in a specialized environment, and it is subject to requirements not written by me.)

Comment: Possibly a silly question but... does this need to be achieved *solely* via the application itself rather than the window manager config?

Comment: _However, right clicking on the window title still shows a popup menu_ A frameless window wouldn't have a title? If you want/need a title, you could fake one by a `QLabel`. As you still can fall back to plan B (restart of application), this would be a rather cheap fix to your right-mouse-button-system-menu issue. Of course, there would still be the window movement part which you had to do on your own in this case...

Comment: @G.M.: Window manager config is ok too, as long as it can be configured for a specific window (as there are other windows that need full functionality).

Comment: `setWindowFlags(windowFlags() & ~(Qt::WindowMinimizeButtonsHint | Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint));` works as expected for me but not `setWindowFlags(windowFlags() & ~(Qt::WindowMinMaxButtonsHint | Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint));`. It seems that there is something wrong with `Qt::WindowMaximizeButtonHint` that i cannot disable as well. ( using Xfce )

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20830004/qt-application-in-kiosk-mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer to your initial question is Yes.

From your question, I am not sure of all the combinations you have tried and what doesn't work for each. It isn't clear if any of the QtWindowsFlags other than Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint are working for you.

[The following Qt5 widgets windowflags example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-windowflags-example.html) provides something you can use to test the behavior of the various WindowFlags.

Between using Window Flags, WindowRole, you should be able to set [_NET_WM_ALLOWED_ACTIONS and _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-latest.html)  using Qt5 via XCB and Metacity should respect it as per their [compliance](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/metacity/blob/master/COMPLIANCE) file.

From examining the source code as long as recalc_window_features is called, then both the title bar if any and the right click menu shouldn't have close or minimize.The relevant source code for this located at [here](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/xcb/qxcbwindow.cpp.html#_ZN10QXcbWindow15setMotifWmHintsE6QFlagsIN2Qt10WindowTypeEE) and [here](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/xcb/qxcbwindow.cpp.html#_ZN10QXcbWindow14setWindowFlagsE6QFlagsIN2Qt10WindowTypeEE) on the Qt5 side, and [here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/metacity/blob/master/src/core/window.c#L6785) on the Metacity side, in case you need to patch, trace or debug further.

As suggested by [Scheff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7478597/scheff), one way of solving your problem is setting FramelessWindowHint, however I believe based on my inspection of the code that you will have more luck setting window flags in order to trigger the special case located [here](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/xcb/qxcbwindow.cpp.html#1005).

E.g.

```
Qt::WindowFlags flags = windowFlags();
flags |= Qt::CustomizeWindowHint;
flags |= Qt::WindowTitleHint;
flags |= Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint;
flags &= ~Qt::WindowMinimizeButtonHint;
flags &= ~Qt::WindowMaximizeButtonHint;
flags &= ~Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint;
```

The code example above is untested.

I believe what you were missing was the `CustomizeWindowHint`, without it the flags get set to default values if the window type is QWindow as per [here](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/xcb/qxcbwindow.cpp.html#960).

Another Stackoverflow question that may be related is [Fullscreen for QDialog from within MainWindow only working sometimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12645880/fullscreen-for-qdialog-from-within-mainwindow-only-working-sometimes) , but it is more about having a QDialog behave like a QWindow to bypass a Metacity bug.

Comment: The `Qt::CustomizeWindowHint` was exactly what I needed for the other flags to have the desired effect. I also solved the problem of the right click title bar menu (I didn't want it) by setting `action-right-click-titlebar='none'` in `org/gnome/desktop/wm/preferences`.